# ArryIndexOutOfBoundsException in counter using arrays

Tags: arrays, random, counter, indexoutofboundsexception

```
public class AssignmentChapter8
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int oddNumbers[] = new int[100];
        int evenNumbers[] = new int[100]; 
        int counter = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int placeholder;

        while(counter < 100)
        {
            placeholder = (int)(Math.random() * 25);

            if(placeholder % 2 > 0)
            {
                oddNumbers[x] = placeholder;
                x++;
            }
            else
            {
                evenNumbers[y] = placeholder;
                y++;
            }
        }   

        System.out.println("The odd numbers are:");

        for(int k = 0; k < 100; k++)
            System.out.print("\t" + oddNumbers[k]);

        System.out.println("The even numbers are:");

        for(int l = 0; l < 100; l++)
            System.out.print("\t" + evenNumbers[l]);
    }
}
```

I have recently started java and am trying to write a program to generate 100 random integers, then sort them into even and odds and display them via arrays. I can compile the above code but am unable to execute it. I continually receive a Out Of Bounds Exception. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't increasing your counter, so essentially have you an infinite loop going. Eventually, x or y gets to 100, and you hit the Out Of Bounds exception for the size of your array (oddNumbers or evenNumbers).

You need to add a `counter++;` line somewhere within the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

A small tweak that you should make is (in addition to fixing the infinite loop):

```
public class AssignmentChapter8
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int oddNumbers[] = new int[100];
        int evenNumbers[] = new int[100]; 
        int counter = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int placeholder;

        while(counter < 100)
        {
            placeholder = (int)(Math.random() * 25);

            if(placeholder % 2 > 0)
            {
                oddNumbers[x] = placeholder;
                x++;
            }
            else
            {
                evenNumbers[y] = placeholder;
                y++;
            }
            // Change 1:
            counter++;
        }   

        System.out.println("The odd numbers are:");
        // change 2:
        for(int k = 0; k < x; k++)
            System.out.print("\t" + oddNumbers[k]);

        System.out.println("The even numbers are:");
        // change 2:
        for(int l = 0; l < y; l++)
            System.out.print("\t" + evenNumbers[l]);
    }
}
```

First change: You weren't incrementing your counter, which yielded an infinite loop (pushing either x or y over 100 causing your array to spill over).

Second change: Although the remainder of your arrays are initialized to zero by default, it would probably be nicer if your for loops stopped at the end of the list of even/odd numbers, x holds the number of odd numbers and y holds the number of even numbers, so you can terminate your for loops at them instead of 100 (which could result in a long chain of zeros for however long the remainder of your lists are).